# NSDateComponents formatting issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using several `NSDateComponents` to display a clock whose individual values are broken up throughout the screen but I'm having formatting troubles.

The seconds display 1-60 not 00-59, and the hours are in 24hr format not 12. Is there any way to format these differently?

Right now I've got the values coming through as an NSInteger, transfering them to a NSString and applying the string to a UILabel. Can anyone help?

is there a `@"%"` format i should be using? (right now i'm using `@"d"`) And if so where could I find a list of those different types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already have the values as `NSInteger` then assuming they are called `minutes` and `hours` first:

```
minutes -= 1; // convert 1 -> 60 to 0 -> 59
if(hours > 12) hours -= 12; // convert 13 -> 24 to 1 -> 12
```

Now to format them both use `"%02d"` - broken down that is 0 - zero padding, 2 - field width, d - decimal integer.

You can find all the format specifications (apart from %@ for objects) by looking up the documentation on `printf`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured there was a quick fox for these I just wasnt sure about the best way. On the "%02d", is there a place where all of these different formats are laid out or explained? but again you really helped me out.

Comment: ow you had already put that. sorry Im just spacing out. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use an NSDateFormatter to format your dates and times into NSStrings.

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01.02.1989"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// Convert my date object into yyyy-mm-dd string object
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *formattedStringDate = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:date];
```

There is a list of date/time formatting codes here: [Date formatting](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/df100103.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007972-SW1)

I hope this helps!
N

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this earlier, try checking out this link. It lists all of the various date formatters and how they work. 
http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

For your particular problem, I think you want h:mm:ss a. h gives the hour, mm for the minutes, ss for the seconds (it's possible s might be the one with 0 padding, I'm not sure), and a gives the AM/PM format.
Also, %d is the correct format for integers, I believe %@ is the correct format for other strings.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the NSDateComponents to an NSDate via NSCalendar and then use an NSDateFormatter (you can use one date formatter per piece if you want):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:yourDateComponents];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[formatter setTimeStye:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
[formatter release];
```

Note that this will use the user's time format; see the documentation for using custom formats.